# How to open a new tab/window via server side code

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, vb.net

Hi this one should be easy but I am having difficulty getting it completed. So I have a webforms app and in the code behind I am building a PDF as byte array, then I am shooting this data of to another page (as this page can build all sorts of bytes depending what is passed to it) to build the PDF via the httpContext below.

```
Response.ClearContent()
HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders()
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = _ContentType
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear()
HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "Filename=" & _Name)
HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Write(_Data, 0, _Data.Length)
HttpContext.Current.Response.End()
```

With this I can do a response.redirect and the PDF opens, however I would like it if the PDF opens in another window/tab. I tried window.open via JS using the page.clentscript.registerstartupscript block and it works with one slight issue and that is popup blockers.

After discovering how popup blockers blocks the window.open action, is there another way to accomplish what I am trying to do. I want to open the PDF in another page so users can continue working on the website.

Thank for your help.

Comment: Where have you place this code? is it inside a button or <a> element? you can place target="_blank"  in a asp:Button and in the YourButtonName_Click call a response.redirect(url_to_call)

Comment: How would I go about that? If i call a _blank target won't that just redirect me to another page. It does not hit my code which searches the db and builds the PDF. I do not want to get into creating different aspx pages for different PDFs creation.